# problem with spring server when create a new page in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am newbie with Rails and trying to work with Rails in both Ubuntu and Windows.

When I worked with Rails in Windows, I tried to create 2 new pages named location and faction by this simple commmand `rails g controller pages faction location`

and it created for me very fast, no problem.

But in ubuntu, I met this problem. It said to me that `Starting Spring server with 'home/nguyencuc2306/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/bin/spring server --background timed out after 20 seconds`

My rails version is 6.1.0 and ruby version is 3.0.0, so I thought that I must create it fast, with no problem. By the way, I am using wireless TP-link to connect to the internet, I thought that may be it is the reason ?

Could you please give me some ideas ? Thank you very much.

Comment: Starting a local development server would not, under normal circumstances, involve any need for an internet connection.

Comment: Is `background timed out after 20 seconds` really the full error message? Is there more information in `logs/development.log`, for example?